# Webpack with babel-loader property types

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to migrate my node typescript apps (with exprees js server) to ES2015 with using Webpack. 
First of all, I would like to use property types. I founded, than I need to user babel-loader and eslint. So, I installed this packages and implement it to my express app.:

**This is my *webpack.config.js***

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackErrorNotificationPlugin = require("webpack-error-notification");
module.exports = 
{
    entry: './src/test/test.js',
    target: 'node',
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'test.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loaders: ['eslint'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }],
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
        }]
    },
    eslint: {
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
        }),
        new WebpackErrorNotificationPlugin()
    ]
}
```

***.eslintrc***

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": false
  }
}
```

**And one of error codes:**

```
export class CmsUserModel {
    /**
     * (description)
     * 
     * @type {String}
     */
    template: string;

    /**
     * (description)
     * 
     * @type {string}
     */
    pages: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.template = "";
        this.pages = new Array<string>();
    }

       public static ToModel(model: ICmsUserModel) {
         return <CmsUserModel>{
             template : model.template,
             pages : model.pages
         };       
     }
}
```

There are two problems. The first is, then babal-eslint error handling is not too specified. For example this:

```
ERROR in ./src/models/cmsUserModel.js

/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/cms/src/models/cmsUserModel.js
  44:40  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


ERROR in ./src/models/cmsUserModel.js
Module build failed: Error: Module failed because of a eslint error.

/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/cms/src/models/cmsUserModel.js
  44:40  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

It's fine, but I would like to see standard error handling like in default webpack and babel loader with print current error line if is possible..?

And the second error is, then I still cannot use property Types as for example: `template: string`

What's wrong please?
Thank's for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following steps,

```
1. npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
2. Add query: { presets: ['es2015'] } to your webpack config with the babel loader.

loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: { presets: ['es2015'] }
        }]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Problem with display errors was solved, but not compilation errors. The same error with row:  **template: string;**  and **unexpected token ':'**

Comment: Is CmsUserModel an ES6 module?